# Using a hyperlink in flash AS3 to an external site

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am using a `TextArea` in flash and setting its `htmlText` property to contain the following link:

```
txtMyTextArea.htmlText = "some dynamic text here that ends in you can check this out <a href=\"http://www.google.co.uk\" target=\"_blank\">here</a>";
```

It works fine when I test it in flash (CTRL + Enter), although when I open the generated HTML I get the following error dialog:

[image]

How can I make the link work without receiving the security dialog?

**Please keep in mind I am not in control of client machines, only the server.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can block the pop-up and let your SWF always connect to external sites. By visiting the link below , But beware there is a lot of potential risks too.

Just visit the below link and select "Always allow".

http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

Comment: That will only allow the flash to work on my machine? What about all the other users that access it when I put it online?

Comment: Are u going to host it via website  ? If so, the end-users doesn't have to do the above process.

Comment: Its secure. You don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the Flash plugin detects a file on your local disk tries to open a link. Like the popup says you should add your swf's path to the Flash safelist. You could consider adding your workspace or even

http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

When you put your file online it'll work without the warning.